# LLDB "step in" and "finish" to get return value of standard functions

Tags: c, gdb, lldb

Is there a way to `step` into standard functions like printf() or atof(), and then execute `finish` to get back to the main program to get the return value?

With GDB I can do it like this:

```
(gdb) step
14          float di = atof(argv[1]);
(gdb) step
atof (nptr=0x7fffffffe0c6 "5.8") at atof.c:27
27      atof.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb) finish
Run till exit from #0  atof (nptr=0x7fffffffe0c6 "5.8") at 
atof.c:27
0x00005555555547d1 in main (argc=2, argv=0x7fffffffdd18) at 
circumf.c:14
14          float di = atof(argv[1]);
Value returned is $1 = 5.7999999999999998
```

But when I try this with LLDB it steps "over" all standard function. It works with functions inside the program, those I can step into, but not with standard functions. I guess this is a feature, but is there a way around it? I use `step` with LLDB also.

Is there maybe some other way to get the return value from standard functions inside LLDB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like gdb, lldb will step into any function that you have debug information for.  It will skip over any function that does not have debug information.  The difference in behavior that you're describing sounds more like lldb doesn't have/hasn't found debug information for your standard library solibs.

Comment: Thanks, I tried GDB and LLDB on the same machine, and then I got consistent behavior. I know realize that I only got different behavior between LLDB and GDB when run on different machines. So you are correct, the difference was probably lack of debug information on the machine on which I ran LLDB.